# Sending emails after updating the model from the admin page (Django)

Tags: django, email, django-admin, django-views

Hello I want to know if there is a way to send an email to a user upon someone updating certain fields in the Django admin page being updated. Is there a way to do this? I already have an email being sent upon the forms completion, but I need to send more emails once one of the users updates through the admin page.

I have taken a look at the post_save, model_save and save_formset methods, but I did not feel that they were what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try overriding the [`ModelAdmin.save_model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) method. I think it has hooks for all the information you require.

The `change` variable lets you distinguish between a user adding or changing the model instance.

`form.changed_data` gives you a list of the names of the fields which have changed, which lets you determine whether or not to send the email.

Finally `request.user` identifies the user which made the changes.

Comment: save_models worked wonderfully. When I first looked at it I didn't think that it was that useful, but it was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

You need `django.db.models.signals.post_save` signal. It is sanding after the model has been saved.

```
def my_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    # Your specific logic here
    pass

post_syncdb.connect(my_callback, sender=yourapp.models.TheModel)
```

Arguments sent with this signal:

- **sender**:
  The model class.
- **instance**:
  The actual instance being saved.
- **created**
  A boolean; True if a new record was created.
- **raw**:
  A boolean; True if the model is saved exactly as presented (i.e. when loading a fixture). One should not query/modify other records in the database as the database might not be in a consistent state yet.

So you need only callback and sender.

Comment: The `post_save` signal gives you the instance being saved - but I don't think it's possible to tell which fields have changed. You might be able to use the `pre_save` signal instead, but overriding the model admin `save_model` method is probably easier.

Comment: But some dirtier. Almost every saving issue you can solve by overriding `save` method, but Django have incapsulated methods which is committed to solve specific issues. Using methods specially committed to solve THE problem you prevent "Newspaper" in your `save` method.

Comment: I was suggesting that the OP override the model admin's `save_model` method, not the model's `save` method.